# how to set user status offline when he/she leaves my website

Tags: facebook, offline, browser-close

I am working on a website in php. how do we set user status to offline in databse when he leaves website by closing browser without click on logout button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  // Do your AJAX call here to set it to offline
});
```